# How to read multiple files one by one and display in the same text area in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I'm doing some coding for an assignment. I'm using java swing to do it. I need to know that how should change my code to display multiple files content in a text area.

I've tried some codes. I added one jButton and one jTextArea to read multiple files. I already know something about setMultiSelectionEnabled(true) and getSelectedFiles().

```
//This is my code inside the jButton

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
    String filename = files.getAbsolutePath();


    try{
       FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
       jTextArea1.read(br, null);

       br.close();
       jTextArea1.requestFocus();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I can only get one file content into my text area yet. Please help me to develop this. Thank you!

Comment: Why, in the *same* text area? Have you considered instead a `JTabbedPane` with one file / text area per tab?

Comment: Because I need to get a specific word count from all the selected files. Ex: If I selected 3 java classes I need to count how many if, while,extends... likewise.

Comment: So why does that prevent you from having multiple tabs? You just create a loop to read the data in each text area on each tab.  In any case you have the answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
       // String filename = files.getAbsolutePath();



           for(File f:files){
           FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
           while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                jTextArea1.append(line);
           }

           br.close();
           //jTextArea1.requestFocus();
         }
```

Comment: I did some small changes. It works fine.Thank you very much for your answer.             
     It should be File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple files in a single text area, then you can't use the `read(...)` method.

Instead you will need to read each file line by line and the add the text to the text area using the `append(...)` method.

Comment: I tried this one. jTextArea.append(selectedFiles.getName()) only the selected file names were displayed. But how to get the content of files. I don't have a good knowledge about arrays, Lists  and BufferedReader.

Comment: We are not here to explain Java to you. If you don't know how to do I/O then it is time to read your text book. Reading data from a file is basic programming and is covered in every text book. Or you can look at the basic [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). Or you can search the forum for code examples that use `BufferedReader`. That is what the forum is for. If you don't know how to use a method, look for an example that uses the method.